# imagen al finalizar un video html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

Hola necesito ayuda con un video, lo que quiero es que al finalizar que ejecute una función con javascrip, quiero que al finalizar el video le pueda dar la clase de d-none y remover la clase d-none de las imagenes que antes, necesito que esta así en autoplay y sin controles

```
<div class="d-none" id="mi-image">
 <img src="/static/images/Head-Video1.png" alt="" class="d-none d-sm-block img-header">
 <img src="/static/images/movil-2.jpg" alt="" class="d-sm-none img-header">
</div>
<video id="video" class="imagen-fondo" autoplay muted poster="/static/images/Head-Video1.png" >
  <source src="static/videos/Herbalife_Greek_Cruise_Teaser_V4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="static/videos/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <img src="static/images/Head-Video1.png" alt="" class="imagen-fondo">
  <img class="imagen-logo" src="static/images/Logo-Intro.png">
</video>`
```

Comment: Si el sentido de la página no es estrictamente el reproducir media NO es recomendable usar autoplay. Mira estas respuestas de UX Exchange https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/when-is-appropriate-to-auto-play-music-or-video-on-a-page y https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13754/why-do-some-webmasters-insist-on-having-auto-playing-music-elements-on-their-web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que necesitas, sería algo así:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended', handlerVideo, false); //Agregar un listener para detectar cuando termina el video y mandarle la función que debe de ejecutar en ese instante

    function handlerVideo(e) {
        var elemento_video = document.getElementById("video"); //Obtener elemento
        elemento_video.classList.add("d-none"); //Agregar clase

        var div_img = document.getElementById("mi-image"); //Obtener elemento
        div_img.classList.remove("d-none"); //Quitar clase
    }
</script>
```